# VBS: Debugging Scripts from vb6, vb.net or C#

Tags: c#, debugging, vbscript, vb.net-2010

I need to implement a vbscript visual debugger. 
That's it. 
I need to know if there is a way to acomplish that from a vb6 or vb.net program.

What I need to do is a visual, step by step, debugger. But, I don't know where to start.

I'd been trying with the "MSScriptControl.ScriptControl" object, but, it only can execute complete code, not step by step support.

Any ideas???

Comment: Visual Studio can debug VBScript/JavaScript... Feels like arbitrary decision. Any particular reason you want implement VBScript debugging over much more documented managed debugging?

Comment: Yes, portability. I need to use this program (the debugger) in many remote environments and, usually I can't count with a full VS suite.
Also, I do not want to buy VbsEdit.

Comment: [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22185) is available, plus I sometimes use [Microsoft Office Script Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189846(v=office.10).aspx) which comes with office. Also, could you parse the commandline output of `cscript.exe` with the `//D` switch?

Comment: actually, I think I meant the `//X` switch

Comment: There's a [Windows Scripting Editors Buyer's Guide](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/scripting/windows-script-editors-140285) which in no way answers your question but may be relevant if $60 is worth less than your time

Comment: I don't see any output in the cscript.exe you mentioned. //X launches a debugger session with, an avaible debugger like, Visual Studio.

I think that, if the people of VbsEdit did it, it is possible, but, we ALL don't know how.

Comment: yeah, sorry I was wrong about the commandline bit. I thought it went into some kind of prompt-based debugging session. Must've been thinking of something else. Microsoft Script Debugger works though, and that's free.

Comment: Yeah, but there is one thing I don't menthioned. Microsoft Script Debugger, only works against an IIS, I can't debug a simple .vbs file.
Or, i can't figure out how :(

Comment: that is strange you can't load a vbs file directly, but (on my PC) the script debugger is in that list of debuggers dialog that appears as you mentioned earlier when using //x or //d cscript switches

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript/VBScript are very old and you are looking for old COM/ActiveX API to work with.
Check out this links - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/03/18/ie8-script-debugger-under-the-hood.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301316.aspx.

Note - I never did it myself and prefer it to stay this way.